# exclamation marks in text file with Pascal

Tags: file, file-io, pascal, turbo-pascal

I have s problem!

I have to define the number of exclamation marks that are in even rows in the text file "T"
Also I have to print lines in which these characters more than two

My programm must be right but PascalABC shows me an error in line #3- "expected type"

Help me please or write your own

```
program text;
var
  T: Text;
  fName: string;
  str: string;
  i: integer;
  numStr: integer;    {Number of current string in file}
  amtSymb: integer;   {count !}
begin
  clrscr;
  write('enter input file name: ');
  readln(fName);
  assign(T,fName); 
  reset(T);          {open file for reading}
  numStr := 0;
  while not EoF(T) do begin  {Reads a line, until we reach the end of file}
    readln(T,str);
    inc(numStr);
    if ((numStr mod 2) = 0) then begin     {If an even line}
      amtSymb := 0;                     
      for i := 1 to length(str) do begin   {We examine each character in the string and read "!"}
        if (str[i] = '!') then
          inc(amtSymb);
      end;
      if (amtSymb > 2) then    {Display the line if more than two "!"}
        writeln(str);
    end;
  end;
  close(T);
  writeln('press any key to exit...');
  readKey;
end.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, it's because of a name clash between your program name `text` and the `Text` file type. Try renaming your program to something else.

Also, in your body you increment numStr before checking if it is even - you probably want the check before the `inc`.